# .Net Core 5 How To Run Appexe On Windows Startup Before Login? (Execute WinForm Before Login & Show Executed Form After Login For Interact = Show GUI)

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a winform application (.exe file) in my windows server 2019 and windows 10 .

This app should auto run when winsows start without login ,
and my code is below , but it now work well ,
how i can fix it

```
    public static void AddApplicationToCurrentUserStartup()
    {
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
        {
       
           if (key.GetValue("MyApplication") == null)
           {
               
                key.SetValue("MyApplication", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString()); 

            }
             
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have an ASP.NET application using Winforms that should run with no user logged in... that seems very weird. What is it supposed to do? Could it be that it *should* actually be *two* different applications, one Windows Service and one UI?

Comment: example:
windows-A has teamViewer , and when window restart  , no need login , use can linked to windows-A 

my app need auto run to get data always  no need user  Manual login when windows restart For whatever reason

Answer (score 1):

You can design your application as a Windows service, then as it detects user logon, make your service execute the WinForm for further interaction.

You can use [ServiceBase.OnSessionChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onsessionchange?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#System_ServiceProcess_ServiceBase_OnSessionChange_System_ServiceProcess_SessionChangeDescription_) and `SessionChangeReason.SessionLogon`. Since this event is under `ServiceBase`, I think you'd need to find another way if you don't want to redesign your application as a service?

update:

Service can achieve what you mentioned in your comment in OP. If configured properly in the service's installer, service will start up after the system is booted.

```
            // Automatically starts up the service after boot up.
            serviceInstaller1.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
```

Comment: thank you for help , 
This is a good idea, I didn't expect it to be like this

Comment: i try to click the anwser but :
Thanks for your feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to vote, but your feedback has been recorded.
sorry

Comment: It's okay, I'm already very glad that I can help you.